# Converting Pixijs v3 AbstractFilter to v4 Filter

Tags: javascript, fragment-shader, pixi.js

I'm trying to convert a custom shader for Pixi v3 to v4.

The original article is here:
http://www.awwwards.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-shaders-with-pixi-js.html

the associated CodePen here
http://codepen.io/omarshe7ta/pen/xVeWWy

So far, I've got this:

```
function CustomFilter(fragmentSource) {
  PIXI.Filter.call(this,
      null,
      fragmentSource
  );
}
CustomFilter.prototype = Object.create(PIXI.Filter.prototype);
CustomFilter.prototype.constructor = CustomFilter;

// smoke shader
var shaderCode = document.getElementById('fragShader').innerHTML
var smokeShader = new CustomFilter(shaderCode);    
smokeShader.uniforms.resolution[0] = width;
smokeShader.uniforms.resolution[1] = height;
smokeShader.uniforms.alpha = 1.0;
smokeShader.uniforms.shift = 1.6;
smokeShader.uniforms.time = 0;
smokeShader.uniforms.speed[0] = 0.7;
smokeShader.uniforms.speed[1] = 0.4;

var bg = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage("pixi_v3_github-pad.png");
bg.width = width;
bg.height = height;
bg.filters = [smokeShader]
stage.addChild(bg);

var logo = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage("pixi_v3_github-pad.png");
logo.x = width / 2;
logo.y = height / 2;
logo.anchor.set(0.5);
logo.blendMode = PIXI.BLEND_MODES.ADD;
stage.addChild(logo)

var count = 0

animate()

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  count += 0.01
  smokeShader.uniforms.time = count;

  renderer.render(stage);
}
```

Edge runs it fine

Chrome throws an error

```
pixi.min.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at e.syncUniforms (pixi.min.js:13)
    at e.applyFilter (pixi.min.js:13)
    at CustomFilter.t.apply (pixi.min.js:13)
    at e.popFilter (pixi.min.js:13)
    at e.renderAdvancedWebGL (pixi.min.js:10)
    at e.renderWebGL (pixi.min.js:10)
    at e.renderWebGL (pixi.min.js:10)
    at e.render (pixi.min.js:13)
    at animate (shader-v4.html:123)
    at shader-v4.html:113
```

FireFox throws an error then crashes the computer.

```
t.uniforms.data[u] is undefined
```

Anyone have ideas what's wrong and how fix it?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable

```
uniform float alpha
```

is not used, so presumably optimised away when the shader is compiled. However, CustomFilter seems oblivious to the fact.

Removing "alpha" from the code solves the problem, commenting it out doesn't. Presumably the shader source is "dumbly" parsed for uniforms and attributes - comments aren't taken into account.

I believe Pixi now uses glsify, so it looks like glslify may have a shortcoming.